# Problem With Getting Started Database CRUD Example

Tags: yii, crud, gii

I have been working through the getting started guide for Yii.  After generating the CRUD code I receive an error when clicking on the "View/Edit/Delete" buttons.  It appears that the generated links are incorrect in that they reference "id" rather than "code" (which is the primary key).

E.g the View link is

http://localhost/yii/demo/basic/web/index.php?r=country%2Fview&id=AU

which generates the error

> Bad Request (#400)
> Missing required parameters: code

when I manually change the link to

http://localhost/yii/demo/basic/web/index.php?r=country%2Fview&code=AU

it works correctly. Why is it referencing "id"?

I also had to modify the CountryController.php file,  findModel function which was again referencing "id"

```
if (($model = Country::findOne($id)) !== null) {
```

when changed to "code" this worked.

```
 protected function findModel($code)
    {
        if (($model = Country::findOne($code)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas,  the db is MySQL and the Code column is defined as the Primary Key.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current yii code.

It expects ID to be the primary key always

A way of fixing it would be to remove the action column from the gridview in index.php and add

```
   [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header' => 'Actions',
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'color:#337ab7'],
            'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}',
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
              if ($action === 'view') {
                  $url ='index.php?r=country/view&code='.$model->code;
                  return $url;
              }
  
              if ($action === 'update') {
                  $url ='index.php?r=country/update&code='.$model->code;
                  return $url;
              }
              if ($action === 'delete') {
                $url ='index.php?r=country/delete&code='.$model->code;
                return $url;
              }
  
            }
            ],
```

Just got done going through old answers regarding how to change gridview to get to this.